# Unable to compile: unrecognized relocation

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, opensuse, ldd

I'm unable to compile anything in my linux pc. I have no idea why, probably I've installed some package and made a mess. I've uninstalled and reinstalled gcc and other packages, but no good news.. still this problem.

This is the message:

```
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-
linux/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: unrecognized relocation (0x29) in section `.text'
```

Any idea of what does it mean and how to fix this problem?

cheers

Comment: Looks like the object file is incompatible with the linker?

Comment: I have gcc (SUSE Linux) 4.8.5
and ldd (GNU libc) 2.25  . I'm hours trying to understand what can it be

Answer (score 21):

For anyone else that encounters this issue: I think @gabib44's problem was using a older version of `ld` to link a library that had been built with a newer version.

"unrecognized relocation" occurs when the relocation type is greater than the greatest known relocation type in your version of `ld`. `0x2a` (`R_X86_64_REX_GOTPCRELX`) is presently the relocation type with the greatest value; I guess @gabib44's `ld` was old enough to not know about the relocation type before that one (`0x29`, `R_X86_64_GOTPCRELX`).

I had this problem myself when I was building a library with binutils v2.26 (which knew about relocation `0x2a`) but then incorporating that library on a build machine using binutils v2.24

The fix is either to build the library that you want to link with a older version of the binutils suite, or to upgrade `ld` on the machine that wants to link that library.

Comment: Just to add details: to upgrade `ld` in ubuntu, I installed binutils-2.26, but that only adds a ld-2.26 binary. I had to handle the symbolic links so that it's used by default.

Answer (score 4):

I've found this in another post:

[...which when compiled brings this error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-
gnu/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-
gnu/6.4.0/../../../../lib64/Scrt1.o: unrecognized relocation (0x2a) in 
section `.text'
```

After trying a lot of things out, including emerging binaries from a different Gentoo system, I finally reverted, and got the problem solved thanks to optiz0r (for solving my issue) and Ryuno-Ki[m] (for letting me know about optiz0rs reply when I had logged off).

```
sudo binutils-config x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-2.29.1
```

Very simple! The solution to your problem may differ, but running

```
sudo binutils-config -l
```

may reveal the version you can enter instead of the version I used...]
by necrophcodr » Tue Feb 06, 2018 21:24
on https://forum.sabayon.org/viewtopic.php?f=57&t=34076&p=181260#p181260

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed installing gcc-32bit and removing various other packets