# unable to compile: unrecognized relocation 0x2a in section text

Tags: gcc, ld, binutils

I have received an error message when compiled "make"

```
$ make
g++ -fopenmp  -o lang.test main.o -I../../../include/Lheader -I../../../include -L../../../lib/ -llmi -lblas -lboost_regex -lpthread -lleveldb
/usr/bin/ld: ../../../lib//liblmi.a(LMInterface.o): unrecognized relocation (0x2a) in section `.text'
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I cannot find any solution for above problem.

GCC version and ld version are like these:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~14.04) 5.4.1 20160904
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


$ ld --version
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.24
Copyright 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or (at your option) a later version.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
```

How to fix this compile problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to compile: unrecognized relocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46058050/unable-to-compile-unrecognized-relocation)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Relocation 42 on x86-64 is `R_X86_64_REX_GOTPCRELX`.  These relocations are used [for optimizations implemented in binutils 2.26 and later](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=commitdiff;h=56ceb5b5405af23eddd12e12d8ba849010120324).

You will either need to upgrade your binutils version, or re-compile the library you want to use with your current toolchain version.

Comment: I installed binutils-2.26 by `apt-get install binutils-2.26`, but it did not work yet. 
`ld --version` commands gives me `GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.24`. 
So, How can I change the version? 
The makefile is like this:
`CC =  g++ -fopenmp`
`CFLAGS = -c -02 -Wall -D_I368 -D_UNIX -fPIC -Wno-unused-result -std=c++11 -Wno-sign-compare`

Answer (score 3):

You need upgrade your GCC version. You can do so by running these commands:

```
yum install centos-release-scl -y
yum install devtoolset-7 -y
scl enable devtoolset-7 bash
```