# /usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value

Tags: r, hash

I am using centOS 7.
I was trying to install 'digest' package on R 3.5.0.

`install.packages('digest')`

But failed compilation with this error :

> /usr/bin/ld: aes.o: unrecognized relocation (0x2a) in section
>   `.text.aes_set_key' /usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: ***[/opt/R/3.5.0/lib64/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: digest.so] Error 1 ERROR:
>   compilation failed for package ‘digest’
>   * removing ‘/opt/R/3.5.0/lib64/R/library/digest’

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: `yum install binutils` solved my problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52737698/unable-to-compile-unrecognized-relocation-0x2a-in-section-text

Answer (score 0):

`yum install binutils binutils-devel` solves the problem. I had the same error with the `gert` R package.